# Array rendering as numbers instead of values

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

When rendering $members array and outputting this code in html, the array becomes 0123456 instead of the values I have requested in the repository.

Controller:

```
public function getMembers(UserRepository $userRepository){

        $members = $userRepository->getAllMembers();

        $entitiyManager=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           return $this->render('leaderboard/leaderboard_Rankings.html.twig',['members' => $members]);

    }
```

Repository:

```
public function getAllMembers(): array 
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

        $query = $entityManager->createQuery(

            'SELECT m.mem_name, m.mem_surname, m.mem_id 
            FROM App\Entity\Member m
            ORDER BY m.mem_name ASC'
        );
        // returns an array of Product objects
        return $query->getResult();
    }
    /**
     * @return User[] Returns an array of User objects
     */
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
   {% for key, item in members %} 
    {{ key }}
{% endfor %}
   </td>
   <td>
   {{members.mem_name}} //Does not work
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

error is:

```
Key "mem_name" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6" does not exist.
```

or the value prints 0123456

Comment: Put it inside the `for`, and use `item` instead of `members`.

Comment: Thanks you! This has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with:

```
 {% for key, item in members %} 
    {{item.mem_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work.